# Flex Advanced Datagrid Condition Row Background Color

Tags: apache-flex, flex3, styles

I am trying to set the row background color for the advanced data grid control in Flex 3. Does anyone know if this is possible using a style function. Currently my style function looks like:

```
public function myStyleFunc(data:Object, col:AdvancedDataGridColumn):Object 
         {
            if (data["status"] == "PRICING") 
                return {color:0xFF0000 , fontWeight:"bold" , backgroundColor:0xFF0000}; 


            // Return null if the Artist name does not match.
            return null;     
         }
```

However the background color does not change.

I have heard on the grape vine that I may need to override some methods to enable the background color property.

Any help would be appreciated .

Regards Karl

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I have done some thing like that but in my case color was also coming from data also but it will help you.
You have to override the Datagrid and override drawRowBackground method

```
public class CustomDataGrid extends AdvancedDataGrid
    {   

        protected override function drawRowBackground(s:Sprite, rowIndex:int, y:Number, height:Number, color:uint, dataIndex:int):void{
              var XMLdata:XML=rowNumberToData(dataIndex) as XML;               
              if(XMLdata!=null){          
                        if(XMLdata.attribute(Constants.col) != undefined && XMLdata.attribute(Constants.col) != ""){
                            color=XMLdata.attribute(Constants.col);         
                        }else{
                            color=0xFFFFFF;
                        }                            
              }               
              super.drawRowBackground(s,rowIndex,y,height,color,dataIndex);         
        }           
    }
```

By this you can get any data from the row and according to it give the color.