# using graphics to fill an entire row in flex

Tags: apache-flex, graphics, datagrid, fill

I have a DataGrid which I need to change the background colour of specific rows based of a condition. I have got up to this point but only the cell which contains the condition changes the background. I am using the following code as an item renderer. I need the entire row corresponding to that cell to be filled in the same way

```
override protected function updateDisplayList(unscaledWidth:Number, unscaledHeight:Number):void
        {
            super.updateDisplayList(unscaledWidth, unscaledHeight);
            var g:Graphics = graphics;
            g.clear();
            var grid1:AdvancedDataGrid = AdvancedDataGrid(AdvancedDataGridListData(listData).owner);

            //var rowtotal:int = new int(dp[0].length) ;
            if (grid1.isItemSelected(data) || grid1.isItemHighlighted(data))
                return;
            var dp:Array = Array((listData.owner as AdvancedDataGrid).dataProvider);
            var rowtotal:int = new int(dp[0].length) ;

            var i:int= new int(0);

            for (i=0; i < rowtotal; i++)
            {                   

            if (data[AdvancedDataGridListData(listData).dataField]== "NJ")
                 {
                 g.beginFill(0xCC0033);
                 g.drawRect(0, 0, unscaledWidth, unscaledHeight);

                 g.endFill();
                }
            }

      }
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1078596/flex-advanced-datagrid-condition-row-background-color

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/q/20371731/842112, you can edit the same question.. and wait for answers.. no need to post it again